# How to get a specific json value when ng-repeating twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON object which is a parsed representation of a CSV file. I wanted to display it in a tabular format, so I used `ng-repeat` twice:

```
<table class="table left">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="invoice in invoices track by $index">
      <td ng-repeat="data in invoice track by $index">
        <div class="cell" ng-class="{ 'no-dealer': !isDealer(data) }">{{ data }}</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This gets me what I want. However, now based on a specific value (which is a unique code) in the JSON objects, I want to apply the `no-dealer` class on that specific tr/td (doesn't matter). How can I acheive this.

The data is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-repeat create a new scope, so for using the functions from parent scope you will have to use it like this -
`ng-class="{ 'no-dealer': !$parent.$parent.isDealer(data) }"`

Two times $parent to reach the main scope of page

Comment: Thanks! Totally makes sense!

But how can I access the `dealer code` values from the `$parent.$parent.isDealer(xxxx)` method ? Basically I want to check the dealer code against a set of pre occupied json object and then apply the `no-dealer` class to that specific tr/td...

Comment: you are already passing the dealer-code to isDealer function as argument here, just make the checks in the function and return a boolean